# Need to implement a finalizer on a class that uses TcpClient?

Tags: c#, idisposable, finalizer, unmanagedresources

I have a class (say `MyClass`) that uses (has as a private field) a `TcpClient` object. `MyClass` implements `IDisposable` calling `TcpClient.Close` in the `Dispose` method.

My question is should `MyClass` also implement a finalizer to call `Dispose(bool Disposing)` to free the `TcpClient’s` unmanaged resources in case `MyClass.Dispose` is not called by the calling code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No you shouldn't.**

Because **you should never call a method on an other object in a finalizer**, it could have been finalized before your object.

The finalizer of your TcpClient will be called by the garbage collector, so let him do.

The pattern in Dispose is :

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if (disposing)
   { 
      // dispose managed resources (here your TcpClient)
   }

   // dispose your unmanaged resources 
   // handles etc using static interop methods.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you shouldn't.

From [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/10/30/dispose-pattern-and-object-lifetime-brian-grunkemeyer.aspx) excellent post:

> Finalization is fundamentally
>   different from ending an object’s
>   lifetime.  From a correctness point of
>   view, there is no ordering between
>   finalizers (outside of a special case
>   for critical finalizers), so if you
>   have two objects that the GC thinks
>   are dead at the same time, you cannot
>   predict which finalizer will complete
>   first.  This means you can’t have a
>   finalizer that interacts with any
>   finalizable objects stored in instance
>   variables.

This is my reference implementation of the disposable/finalize pattern with comments explaining when to use what:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Example of how to implement the dispose pattern.
    /// </summary>
    public class PerfectDisposableClass : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Type constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public PerfectDisposableClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Constructing" );    
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose method, disposes resources and suppresses finalization.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose( true );
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes resources used by class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">
        /// True if called from user code, false if called from finalizer.
        /// When true will also call dispose for any managed objects.
        /// </param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Dispose(bool disposing) called, disposing = {0}", disposing );

            if (disposing)
            {
                // Call dispose here for any managed objects (use lock if thread safety required), e.g.
                // 
                // if( myManagedObject != null )
                // {
                //     myManagedObject.Dispose();
                //     myManagedObject = null;
                //  }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the finalizer.  Note that if <see cref="Dispose()"/> has been called then finalization will 
        /// have been suspended and therefore never called.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This is a safety net to ensure that our resources (managed and unmanaged) are cleaned up after usage as
        /// we can guarantee that the finalizer will be called at some point providing <see cref="Dispose()"/> is
        /// not called.
        /// Adding a finalizer, however, IS EXPENSIVE.  So only add if using unmanaged resources (and even then try
        /// and avoid a finalizer by using <see cref="SafeHandle"/>).
        /// </remarks>
        ~PerfectDisposableClass()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any comments on my *Perfect* (I don't believe that for an instant, but it's my best to date ;) class welcome.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to. TcpClient is a wrapper class around the unmanaged socket and there for it is managed the way it should be disposed. What you have done is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should - [Microsoft even recommends it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(VS.71).aspx).

Just remember that belt-and-suspenders code never gets you called into the office at 2:00AM :)